# Facebook Comments Mirroring not working

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook Page for my blog named **PeppyBurro**. And I have a Facebook App named **PeppyBurro Blue**. I am using this app's app ID to embed FB comments on my blog. The comments section is live and working fine.

[image]

I can even moderate the comments on my moderation page:

[image]

Now I want to enable Facebook Comments Mirroring in this app's settings so that the comments entered on the website appear on the corresponding post on the FB page and vice-versa. However, when I attempt to do that, FB tells me I don't have a page to connect!

[image]

For what it's worth, I already have Instant Articles up and running on my page.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem: It's not possible to activate mirroring to post to personal Facebook profiles. It only works with Facebook pages (sites). In order to use this feature you have to create a Facebook page (with your profile) and post to it.